# Latex pgfplots: Scope inset plot in groupplot

Tags: latex

I am currently trying to organize three plots using the `groupplot` environment of the LaTeX package `pgfplots`.

That's actually no problem, and I have done this several times before. However, this time, each sub-plot is supposed to have a little inset plot. `pgfplots` has a nice feature for this, called `scope` environment.

My problem: `groupplot` and inset figures do not seem to work together properly. Has anyone ever encountered the same issue, or has a suggestion how to create a `groupplot` plot where each plot has an inset plot?

The result should look like this:

[image]

I have studied the gnuplot manual in detail and searched on the Internet a lot. So far, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

The \matrix{} command is the one I was looking for. So, for future reference, here is how it is properly done

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix{

        \begin{axis}
            plot code ...
        \end{axis}

        \begin{scope}
            \begin{axis}
                plot code ...
            \end{axis}
        \end{scope}

    \\

        \begin{axis}
            plot code ...
        \end{axis}

        \begin{scope}
            \begin{axis}
                plot code ...
            \end{axis}
        \end{scope}

    \\
        \begin{axis}
            plot code ...
        \end{axis}

        \begin{scope}
            \begin{axis}
                plot code ...
            \end{axis}
        \end{scope}

    }

\end{tikzpicture}
```